# Editing SQL in JAVA where must be boolean

Tags: java, sql

I'm editing SQL in JAVA but keep getting ERROR

If I'm understanding it correctly, if state is OK I should get

```
SELECT name FROM inventura_table where state='O'
```

when I execute same select by script it works just fine

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            String SQL = "SELECT name FROM inventura_table where ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);

            ResultSet rs;
            switch (state) {
                case "OK":
                    pstmt.setString(1, "state='O' ");
                    break;
                case "M":
                    pstmt.setString(1, "state='M' ");
                    break;
                case "V":
                    pstmt.setString(1, "state='V' ");
                    break;
                case "removed":
                    pstmt.setString(1, "out_date IS NOT NULL");
                    break;
                }
```

Error

> ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type character
> varying

Comment: the resulting query is something similar to `SELECT name FROM inventura_table where 'state=''O'' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying is not possible. You can only set values to conditions, not create new conditions.

You could do something like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
String SQL = "SELECT name FROM inventura_table";

if (state.equals("removed")) {
  SQL += " where out_date IS NOT NULL";
}
else {
  SQL += " where state = ?";
}

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);

ResultSet rs;
switch (state) {
   case "OK":
      pstmt.setString(1, "O");  
      break;
   case "M":
      pstmt.setString(1, "M");
      break;
   case "V":
      pstmt.setString(1, "V");
      break;
}
```